# Retrofit2 throws Android-related RuntimeException on jvm

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm trying to use retrofit on the JVM(i.e. not on android), and retrofit 1 seems to work fine, but when I switch to retrofit2 I get the following errors at runtime:

```
Error:java: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class 
file for android.os.Handler not found
Error:java: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for 
android.os.Handler not found
```

I haven't done much android development so I'm not entirely sure what "android.os.Handler" is.

How do I fix this?

EDIT:
My dependencies look like this:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>converter-gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>adapter-java8</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to reproduce this on a second machine, but am unable to. It just works fine.

I've concluded that this must be a problem with the build step, and marking it as solved.